# how to make php contact page work

Tags: php

Hello I'm in need of someone how can help me with php, my current php code just takes me to a "Page not found" page so if someonw can tell me how to fix that I would be so happy.

here is the Html:

```
<div>
            <div>
                <p class="text-center" style="font-family:Aparajita; font-size:1.5vw; padding:2%;">Drop me a line</p>
            </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal bu_contact col-lg-4" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label glyphicon glyphicon-user"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

The php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'lars81wolf@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName &#038;& !$errEmail &#038;& !$errMessage &#038;& !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='

<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>


';
    } else {
        $result='

<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>


';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: When do you get "page not found" ? When you submit form ?

Comment: is the `index.php` page ( form target ) in the same folder as this contact page? Try prefixing with a slash ~ `/index.php`

Comment: what is name of your html file..?

Comment: Random yes it goes to a page not found when I submit the form

Comment: My html file is called contect.html

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in one file name it the same as the target basically and all would be fine.

```
<?php
// NAME THIS FILE contact.php so that the post will send it to this file
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'lars81wolf@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName &#038;& !$errEmail &#038;& !$errMessage &#038;& !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        echo '

                <div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>


            ';
        } else {
        echo '

                <div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>


            ';
        }
    }
} else {
// Put all your stuff that will be the normal page in here
?>
<div>
            <div>
                <p class="text-center" style="font-family:Aparajita; font-size:1.5vw; padding:2%;">Drop me a line</p>
            </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal bu_contact col-lg-4" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label glyphicon glyphicon-user"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

But do not forget all the HTML conform head and foot.

PS: I did not check for any further problems just for the routine itself. Not sure if this will really mail anything unless you configured php correctly for the use of an MTA through mail function ;)

Comment: It is all in the same file :/

Comment: Well then the complete file would be interesting and the filename of it.
Because you put stuff in $result but I can not see what or where that will be displayed.

Comment: as you said above the file is named contact.html but you wrote:

<form class="form-horizontal bu_contact col-lg-4" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">

So the send Button send things to index.php.

And if you did not specify that you want php to parse .html files this will never pe parsed by php. Normally it should be named contact.php and the action should post to contact.php.